# Is there a Subversion API that can be used to program against in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, svn

Is there an API to access Subversion from C#?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[**Svn.NET**](http://www.pumacode.org/projects/svndotnet/) is a continuation (fork) of [SubversionSharp](http://www.softec.st/en/OpenSource/ClrProjects/SubversionSharp/SubversionSharp.html) mentioned in [CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287862/subversion-access-from-net#287869). SubversionSharp is limited to the .NET 1.1 platform.

Svn.NET supports the following platforms:

- .NET 2.0 on Windows Platforms
- Mono on Win32 (2.0 framework)
- Mono on Linux (2.0 framework)

Comment: Did you try it? Did you like it? Tell me more about it!

Comment: No commits since 2008, I assume it's dead

Comment: It's the underlying API that AnkhSVN uses.  It is a major product for Visual Studio. So the underlying API it is really good.  It is about as easy as using the command line.  I see that's above @Andrew's head.  Just be sure to get the nightly for 1.7 (current stable is 1.5...but 1.7 is so much better).

Comment: FYI, the link to for SVN.Net is no longer good. I couldn't find a replacement with a quick google search.

Answer (score 24):

[SharpSvn](http://sharpsvn.net/) is a new Subversion wrapper library for .Net/C# that hides all interopand memory management for you and includes a staticly compiled Subversion library for easy integration. It is probably the only Subversion binding designed to perform well in a multithreaded environment.

SharpSvn is not platform independent, but it makes it really easy to use Subversion from your .Net applications. Several projects switched from other libraries to using SharpSvn in the last year. (AnkhSVN, Collabnet desktop for Visual Studio, SharpForge, to name a few)

Comment: +1 - I've used SharpSvn on .NET 2.0 and found it simple to use.

Comment: Excellent. The current (1.6006.1373) crashes VS but the latest nightly build (1.6015.1625) works brilliantly

Answer (score 2):

Check [SubversionSharp](http://www.softec.st/en/OpenSource/ClrProjects/SubversionSharp/SubversionSharp.html), its basically a C# wrapper library that fully covers the client API of Subversion.

Comment: There is a note on the site that at the time it supports exclusively .NET 1.1. If you want .NET 2.0 support you could try SVN.NET.

Answer (score 2):

I tried Svn.NET at one point and remember that it didn't do everything that I was looking for. If Svn.NET works for you I'd definitely recommend that route, but if you have problems like I did you can get wild and try using http://www.ikvm.net/ to convert http://svnkit.com/ to a .NET assembly. I definitely got this to work and was experimenting with it in my project when we decided to move away from SVN after all and I shelved the whole thing.