# are there any Subversion API wrappers available?

Tags: api, svn, svn-api

looking for subversion api wrappers that would let me make calls to subversion via a web application.

any language at this point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org) : you can integrate this with your favorite python web framework.

Comment: @mrblah: does my answer satisfy you?

Answer (score 3):

[SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) is a pure Java Subversion client library.

> SVNKit supports all standard
>   Subversion operations, both on working
>   copies and repository. It is
>   compatible with all versions of
>   Subversion, works over HTTP, SSH, SVN
>   and FILE protocols. It provides API to
>   version virtually any object model
>   with standard Subversion repository;
>   there is no need to keep anything in
>   the filesystem. SVNKit works with local 
>   repositories as well as with remote ones

Features:

- Repository access over http(s), svn, svn(+ssh) and file protocols.
- Working copy operations - all are supported.
- Repository administration: create, load, dump and replay
  operations.
- Additionally to its own API, SVNKit implements JavaHL API.
- SVNKit is reported to work on Windows, OSX, Linux, BSD and OpenVMS.
- SVNKit does not require native binaries, it works out of the box.
- Native Subversion configuration files are used by default.
- Java Subversion command line client is part of SVNKit.
- Latest SVNKit supports Subversion 1.6.5.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.thoughtspark.org/node/11 SharpSvn:

Comment: Direct link: http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/

Comment: if you had a .net web app, could it hook into a unix server though?

Comment: you can run .net apps on linux/unix using mono http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Comment: SharpSvn runs on the client, just like TortoiseSVN. It can connect to any Subversion server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Svn.NET](http://www.pumacode.org/projects/svndotnet/).

And here are some more options for .NET in a similar post:

[Is there a Subversion API that can be used to program against in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287862/is-there-a-subversion-api-that-can-be-used-to-program-against-in-net)

Comment: Svn.NET is as dead as a dodo.